# Image won't stop rotating in pygame

Tags: image, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.2

I have this section of code (similar to the previous piece of code). It's supposed to just sweep 50 degrees left, then stop and sweep 100 degrees right, then stop and sweep 100 degrees to the left, and so forth. Only problem is it stops at the left, goes right, then continues to go right, even though I have a stop there to prevent that from happening.

```
                try:
                    screen.blit(Turrets[1], (TurretCoords[1]))
                    if Rotation == 1:
                        print(TurretRotation[1])
                        print(Rotation)
                        TurretRotation[1] = TurretRotation[1] - 1
                        Turrets[1] = pygame.transform.rotozoom(Turret, TurretRotation[1], 1)
                        if TurretRotation[1] == -50:
                            Rotation = -1
                    else:
                        print(TurretRotation[1])
                        print(Rotation)
                        TurretRotation[1] = TurretRotation[1] + 1
                        Turrets[1] = pygame.transform.rotozoom(Turret, TurretRotation[1], 1)
                        if TurretRotation[1] == 50:
                            Rotation = 1
```

Yes, I know, I was supposed to change the variables capital letters, and I haven't gotten around to it yet.
This is the output I get from the console.

```
-1 = Rotate
1 = TurretRotation[1]
-1
2
-1
3
-1
4
-1
5
-1
6
-1
7
-1
8
-1
9
-1
10
-1
11
-1
12
-1
13
-1
14
-1
15
-1
16
-1
17
-1
18
-1
19
-1
20
-1
21
-1
22
-1
23
-1
24
-1
25
-1
26
-1
27
-1
28
-1
29
-1
30
-1
31
-1
32
-1
33
-1
34
-1
35
-1
36
-1
37
-1
38
-1
39
-1
40
-1
41
1
40
1
39
1
38
1
37
1
36
1
35
1
34
1
33
1
32
1
31
1
30
1
29
1
28
1
27
1
26
1
25
1
24
1
23
1
22
1
21
1
20
1
19
1
18
1
17
1
16
1
15
1
14
1
13
1
12
1
11
1
10
1
9
1
8
1
7
1
6
1
5
1
4
1
3
1
2
1
1
1
0
1
-1
1
-2
1
-3
1
-4
1
-5
1
-6
1
-7
1
-8
1
-9
1
-10
1
-11
1
-12
1
-13
1
-14
1
-15
1
-16
1
-17
1
-18
1
-19
1
-20
1
-21
1
-22
1
-23
1
-24
1
-25
1
-26
1
-27
1
-28
1
-29
1
-30
1
-31
1
-32
1
-33
1
-34
1
-35
1
-36
1
-37
1
-38
1
-39
1
-40
1
-41
1
-42
1
-43
1
-44
1
-45
1
-46
1
-47
1
-48
1
-49
1
-50
1
-51
1
-52
1
-53
1
-54
1
-55
1
-56
1
-57
1
-58
1
-59
1
-60
1
-61
1
-62
1
-63
1
-64
1
-65
1
-66
1
-67
1
-68
1
-69
1
-70
1
-71
1
-72
1
-73
1
-74
1
-75
1
-76
1
-77
1
-78
1
-79
1
-80
1
-81
1
-82
1
-83
1
-84
1
```

Comment: Better `print(TurretRotation[1], Rotation)` to get both variables in one line. Or even `print('%4d %4d % (TurretRotation[1], Rotation) )` to get result better formatted.

Comment: `TurretRotation` changes 1...41 then 41...-84 . Maybe there was some problem before `if TurretRotation[1] ...` was executed so it didn't change direction but `try` catched that problem and you got no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't run it so I can only advice - I see you have `print` - so see what's going on with variables. Maybe one of them is changed in different place.

But you can do one this - use `<=` and `>=` - it should help.

```
if TurretRotation[1] >= 50:

if TurretRotation[1] <= -50:
```

Comment: Thanks. I could give you the full code for you to run it if you want.

Comment: First try your skills to find problem :)

Comment: I can't get it to work. I added the output from the IDLE window (or CMD or Terminal). The rotation number eventually gets so big that the game crashes entirely.

Comment: So better checks with `>=` and `<=` then with `==`. If you get `-70` then `-70 <= -50` and it should change direction but `-70 == -50` will not change it.

Comment: I tried it with the <= 50 but it still goes on and on.

Comment: Sorry, not `<= 50` but `>= 50` and `<= -50`.